# PHP has encountered an access violation at (random memory location)

Tags: php, iis

I am using Window Server 2003 machine , and PHP 5.2.9 and it is configured to use SQL Server 2005 as Backend by making use of Microsoft SQL Server Driver.

But while executing bulk queries i some times get error **"PHP has encountered an access violation at (random memory location)"** after showing this error server just stops giving any response.

After restarting IIS evreything again works fine..

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be some PHP bug, try updating the PHP version.

Comment: Thanx @Gedrox i'll try and let u knw the outcome... thnx a lot for your suggestion...